# Find a cumulative sum of one column until a conditional sum on another column is met

Tags: r, cumsum

I would like to find the preceding cumsum (i.e. cumsum minus the present row) for those rows of column B until the sum of the previous rows of column A including present row is <= 7.

I was able to find an answer using a traditional for loop. A vectorized implementation would be very helpful as I need to run it on a large dataset. Sharing my simple code in case it helps.

```
dt <- data.frame(A = c(0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 90, 8, 2, 4, 1, 2),
                 B = c(1, 0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1),
                 Ans = c(0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6),
                 new=rep(0,11))



dt3 <- dt
for (i in 2:nrow(dt3)){
  set<-0
  count<-0
  k=i-1
  for (j in k:1){
    count=count+dt3$A[j+1]
    if(count<=7){ 
      set<-set+dt3$B[j]
      if(j==1){
        dt3$new[i]=set
      }
    }
    else{
      dt3$new[i]=set
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the 3 conditions to be satisfied:

1. If A > 7, then Ans resets to 0
2. If cumsum(A)<=7, then Ans is cumsum() of lagB
3. If cumsum(A) > 7, then Ans is cumsum() of lagB for the range of previous rows of A for which the sum is <=7

Here is a simplified version of the data (Column A and B) and the desired output is the Column Ans:

```
dt <- data.frame(A = c(0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 90, 8, 2, 4, 1, 2),
                 B = c(1, 0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1),
                 Ans = c(0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6))

dt
    A B Ans   Reason for value in Ans:
1   0 1   0       There are no preceeding rows in B so Ans is 0
2   2 0   1       Sum of value of A from row 2 to 1 is 2 <=7. So Ans is the value of B from first row = 1
3   3 4   1       Sum of value of A from row 3,2 and 1 is 5 <=7. So Ans is the sum of value of B in row 1 and 2, which is 1. 
4   5 2   4       Value of A from row 4 is 5 which is <=7. So Ans is value of B from row 3, which is 4
5   8 3   0       Value of A in row 5 is 8 which is >7. So Ans is 0 (Value of Ans resets to 0 when A > 7).
6  90 4   0
7   8 2   0
8   2 1   2        Value of A in row 8 is 2 which <=7, so Ans is value of B in row 7 which is 2
9   4 2   3        Sum of value of A from row 9 and 8 is 6<=7, so Ans is sum of value of B in row 8 and 7 = 3
10  1 3   5        Sum of value of A from row 10,9 and 8 is 7<=7, so Ans is sum of value of B in row 9,8 and 7 =5.
11  2 1   6        Sum of value of A from row 11,10 and 9 is 7<=7, so Ans is sum of value of B in row 10,9 and 8 =6.
```

Any help on how can I code this in R?

Comment: I have replaced your scrfeenshot with a code to generate your data frame. Next time, please do not use screenshot to show your data. Provide reproducible example dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Will keep in mind next time

Comment: Those downvotes may be partly due to the earlier screenshot. I have fixed that. Now perhaps you can further clarify the logic of your expected output. I guess some people could not understand your logic so they gave you downvotes. It would be helpful if you can explain row by row why each number in Ans are like that, perhaps until row 5.

Comment: My downvote was for lack of effort.  This reads like a "give me code" question, because it is.

Comment: I tried coding this in R, but I really couldnt get any further other than trying different ways of doing cumsum with a mutate and ifelse statement using the dplyr package. Any help will be great! Thanks

Comment: Why is `Ans` in row 9 and 10 equal to `3,5`?

Comment: @ChiPak - I just added the explanation for those rows in the main question

Comment: I just saw your updated explanation. It really confused me. Why in row 4 you only add the row 3 and 4 from column A. But for row 9 and 10, you do `cumsum` starting row 8?

Comment: @ycw - I am deciding the cumsum till the row in A uptill which the cumulative sum is <=7. In row 4, the sum of A from row 4 and 3 is >7 so then I only look at value of A from row 4 which is <7. In row 9 and 10, I do cumsum from row 8 itself as the cumsum of A uptill row 8 is <=7. I updated the explanation in the main question again to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please see the edit below** which tries to answer the updated question.

---

If I have understood OP's intention right, then there are 3 rules:

1. if `A` is greater 7 then `Ans` is zero and grouping is restarted
2. if `cumsum(A)` within the group is less or equal 7  then `Ans` is the `cumsum()` of lagged `B`
3. if `cumsum(A)` within the group is greater 7  then `Ans` is lagged `B`

The code below produces the expected result for the given sample data set:

```
# create sample data set
DF <- data.frame(A = c(0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 90, 8, 2, 4, 1),
                 B = c(1, 0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3),
                 Ans = c(0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5))
# load data.table, CRAN version 1.10.4 used
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table
DT <- data.table(DF)
# create helper column with lagged values of
DT[, lagB := shift(B, fill = 0)][]
# create new answer
DT[, new := (A <= 7) * ifelse(cumsum(A) <= 7, cumsum(lagB), lagB), by = rleid(A <= 7)][
  , lagB := NULL][]
```

> ```
>      A B Ans new
>  1:  0 1   0   0
>  2:  2 0   1   1
>  3:  3 4   1   1
>  4:  5 2   4   4
>  5:  8 3   0   0
>  6: 90 4   0   0
>  7:  8 2   0   0
>  8:  2 1   2   2
>  9:  4 2   3   3
> 10:  1 3   5   5
> ```

`rleid(A <= 7)` creates unique group numbers for all consecutive streaks of `A` values not greater or greater of 7, resp. The `ifelse()` clause implements rules 2 and 3 within the grouping. By multiplying the result with `(A <= 7)`, rule 1 is implemented., thereby using the trick that `as.numeric(TRUE)` is 1 and `as.numeric(FALSE)` is 0. Finally, the helper column is removed.

---

#### Edit

With the additional information provided by the OP, I believe there is *only one* rule left:

- for each row find a window extending backwards which contains as many rows as `sum(A)` does not exceed 7. The answer is the sum of lagged `B` in the same window.
- For clarification, if the window has zero length because `A` in the inital row already exceeds 7, then the answer is zero.

The variable length of the sliding window is the tricky part here:

```
# sample data set consists of 11 rows after OP's edit
DF <- data.frame(A = c(0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 90, 8, 2, 4, 1, 2),
                 B = c(1, 0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1),
                 Ans = c(0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6))
DT <- data.table(DF) 
DT[, lagB := shift(B, fill = 0)][]

# find window lengths
DT[, wl := DT[, Reduce(`+`, shift(A, 0:6, fill = 0), accumulate = TRUE)][, rn := .I][
  , Position(function(x) x <= 7, right = TRUE, unlist(.SD)), by = rn]$V1][]

# sum lagged B in respective window
DT[, new := DT[, Reduce(`+`, shift(lagB, 0:6, fill = 0), accumulate = TRUE)][
  , rn := .I][, wl := DT$wl][, ifelse(is.na(wl), 0, unlist(.SD)[wl]), by = rn]$V1][]
```

> ```
>      A B Ans lagB wl new
>  1:  0 1   0    0  7   0
>  2:  2 0   1    1  7   1
>  3:  3 4   1    0  7   1
>  4:  5 2   4    4  1   4
>  5:  8 3   0    2 NA   0
>  6: 90 4   0    3 NA   0
>  7:  8 2   0    4 NA   0
>  8:  2 1   2    2  1   2
>  9:  4 2   3    1  2   3
> 10:  1 3   5    2  3   5
> 11:  2 1   6    3  3   6
> ```

Comment: Thanks Uwe! Conditions 1 and 2 are right. For condition 3 it is : If cumsum(A) within group is > 7, then answer is cumsum() of lagged B for the set of cumulative rows of A for which the sum is <=7

Comment: I've derived rule 3 from your explanation of the answer in row 4: _Value of A from row 4 is 5 which is <=7. So Ans is value of B from row 3, which is 4_

Comment: Yes, that is true for row 4. But it should not hold true for row 9, 10 where cumsum(A) > 7.

Comment: Isn't `cumsum(A)` restarted after each row with `A > 7`, i.e, after row 7 with `A == 8`? So, `cumsum()` of rows 8 to 10 is 2+4+1 == 7.

Comment: You know, @sharp all this time spent explaining your problem could have been better spent learning R and writing some code yourself.

Comment: @RichScriven IMHO, the challenge for the OP is to describe the problem and to specify the expected result.

Comment: @UweBlock - Thanks for your help! I have added row 11 to the data in the main question which provides a situation where cumsum(A) > 7, but Ans is not lagged(B)

Comment: @RichScriven - I did try running code myself yday before posting here. As I was unable to make any decent progress, I thought of requesting for help.

Comment: Uh, then the problem is much more complex as there is a kind of rolling window which extends backwards as many rows as long as the sum is not exceeding 7. That's really tricky.

Comment: @UweBlock - Yes. I am happy that I was able to at least finally communicate my true problem.

Comment: @UweBlock - Thanks a lot for the solution. I will work on understanding the finer aspects of the code.